# Django rest framework serializer.save() not saving to database and shows ConnectionAbortedError:

Tags: mongodb, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer, djoser

I'm trying to `PUT` some data into `UserAccount` model in order to reset the password without using web template(for a mobile app). Here the model

```
class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_password_reset_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    password_reset_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

The data I send won't save. But returns the `Success response 204`. Heres my **serializer.py**

```
class UserAccountPasswordResetConfirmationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserAccount
        fields = ['is_password_reset_confirmed', 'password_reset_token']
```

**views.py**

```
class UserPasswordResetConfirmView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, uid, token, format=None):
        payload = {
            'is_confirmed': True,
            'token': token
        }

        url = 'http://localhost:8000/password/reset/confirmed/{}/'.format(smart_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uid)))
        response = requests.put(url, data=payload)

        if response.status_code == 204:
            return Response(response.content)
        else:
            return Response({"Error": "Failed to Confirm"})


class UserPasswordResetView(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return UserAccount.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except UserAccount.DoesNotExist:
            raise Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        user = self.get_object(pk)
        # print("Data", request.data)
        serializer = UserAccountPasswordResetConfirmationSerializer(user, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I checked whether the data are passing to `UserPasswordResetView` from `UserPasswordResetConfirmView` using `print` statements(^.^') and there's no problem in that.

```
 Data <QueryDict: {'is_confirmed': ['True'], 'token': ['5m0-60f758fc23628d143158']}>
```

But the `response.content` returns "" and the data won't update.

Addition to that console indicates,

```
[30/Nov/2020 14:56:05] "PUT /password/reset/confirmed/1/ HTTP/1.1" 204 63
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 64019)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "C:\Users\Ozunu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "C:\Users\Ozunu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
----------------------------------------
[30/Nov/2020 14:56:05] "GET /password/reset/confirm/MQ/5m0-60f758fc23628d143158/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5540
```

Btw I'm using `MongoDB` and `djoser`. Why is this happening and any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

I've tested the endpoint of the `UserPasswordResetView(APIView)` and it does the updates to the relevant record.

---

**Edit**

I was able to solve the not saving issue by converting

`<QueryDict: {'is_confirmed': ['True'], 'token': ['5m0-60f758fc23628d143158']}>`

to a dictionary

`{'is_confirmed': 'True', 'token': '5m0-60f758fc23628d143158'}`

but unable to solve the `ConnectionAbortedError:` error.

Comment: ConnectionAbortedError is always happening with me on windows, I think there is an issue but it doesn't affect anything at development